# how to add up elements of lists netlogo

Tags: list, mapping, netlogo

I am trying to calculate the average of elements of lists. Therefor I have to add all the first elements of ten lists separate and the second element.. etc.

So far I have this:

```
  set averagec map [ [x] -> item 0 x] finaltable
  set averaged map [ [x] -> item 1 x] finaltable
  set averagegemiddelderan map [ [x] -> item 2 x] finaltable
  set averageunf map [ [x] -> item 3 x] finaltable
  set averagetft map [ [x] -> item 4 x] finaltable
  set averagepav map [ [x] -> item 5 x] finaltable
  set averagetftt map [ [x] -> item 6 x] finaltable
  set averagertft map [ [x] -> item 7 x] finaltable
  set averageswit map [ [x] -> item 8 x] finaltable
  set averagehm map [ [x] -> item 9 x] finaltable
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to produce a list that holds the means across the rows, which I believe is what you asked for.  The first method adds up the rows and then divides by the number of rows.  The second method transposes the list of lists (which is apparently the structure of your `finaltable`) and then maps `mean` across the result.  The `finaltable` must be rectangular in both cases.

```
globals [finaltable]

to setup
  ;fake data (rectangular list of list)
  set finaltable n-values 10 [-> n-values 15 [-> random 100]]
end

to go
  ;first method
  let _sum reduce [[?xs ?ys] -> addvecs ?xs ?ys] finaltable
  let _n length finaltable
  print map [?x -> ?x / _n] _sum
  ;second method
  print map mean transpose finaltable
end


;two helper functions, for the two methods
to-report addvecs [#xs #ys]
  report (map + #xs #ys)
end

to-report transpose [#lstlst]
  let _n length item 0 #lstlst
  let _start fput n-values _n [-> []] #lstlst
  report reduce [[?lstlst ?items] -> (map [[?lst ?item] -> lput ?item ?lst] ?lstlst ?items)] _start
end
```